# Remote Script Execution via SSH command: how to know if it's done correctly or not

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I need to execute a script Linux via SSH with Java, that resides on a remote Linux machine.
At runtime I retrieve from DB the name of the script, the host and the credentials and try to launch via ssh the script. This is OK because I get the execution PID in return!
The problem is that I get always a PID of execution, even if the script is wrong or it doesn't exist or it doesn't have the execution rights.

Is there a way to know if the execution is right or if the command is wrong? I need to know if it is possible in the same ssh launch command. Thank you in advance

The code we are using is this below:

```
   JSch jsch = new JSch();
String post_process_host="123.123.123.123";
Integer post_process_port=22;
String post_process_user="therock";
String post_process_pwd="XxXdfG$L";
//String command="testpp.sh";
String command="./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh";


command=command + " > /dev/null 2>&1 & \n echo $!";
Session session = jsch.getSession(post_process_user, post_process_host, post_process_port.intValue());

UserInfo ui = new SUserInfo(post_process_pwd, null);
session.setUserInfo(ui);
session.setPassword(post_process_pwd);

session.connect();


int timeout=10; //timeout di 5 minuti
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
int exitCode = -1;
try {

    logger.info("Execution command: " + command);

    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    InputStream err = ((ChannelExec) channel).getErrStream();
    channel.connect(timeout);
    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
      timeout--;
      while (in.available() > 0) {
        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if (i < 0)
          break;
        String line = new String(tmp, 0, i, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        text.append(line);
        if (text.toString().contains("\n")) break;
      }
      while (err.available() > 0) {
        int i = err.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if (i < 0)
          break;
        String line = new String(tmp, 0, i, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        text.append(line);
      }
      if (channel.isClosed()) {
        if (in.available() > 0)
          continue;
        exitCode = channel.getExitStatus();
        logger.info("Eseguito comando codice di ritorno: " + exitCode);
        logger.debug("output comando: "+text.toString());
        if (exitCode!=0) throw new Exception("Execution Command "+command+" error with Return Code="+exitCode);
        break;
      }
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (Exception ee) {
        throw ee;
      }
    }

    channel.disconnect();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
  }
logger.debug("output command: "+text.toString());
```

Comment: you might want to parse the output (so don't redirect it to /dev/null) or you might want to capture its exit code (e.g.: ```echo $?```)

Comment: Hi Kristian, thank you. I need to know if a script is lauched. I don't know the business login into the script. I only need to know if the script is correctly lauched. But as is, I get always exicCode = 0 (so OK) even if the script doesn't exist on remote server.

Comment: that's because exit code = 0 is for last command executed, which is ```echo $!```, you can check my answer

Answer (score 1):

The highlight of your code above is on this 2 line:

```
String command="./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh";
command=command + " > /dev/null 2>&1 & \n echo $!";
```

Which made a `command` variable that have such value:

```
./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh > /dev/null 2>&1 & \n echo $!
```

To understand what this command does, you might want to study `bash`, but here's my quick explanation:

- execute a command in file called `./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh` (from its extension, I assume it's a shell script)
- `> /dev/null` = then redirect its `STDOUT` to `/dev/null` (a.k.a.: discard the output)
- `2>&1` = then redirect its `STDERR` to wherever `STDOUT` goes (as stated above, its gone to /dev/null or discarded)
- `&` = execute it in background
- `\n echo $!` = then echo (print in STDOUT) the PID (process id) of the resulting background process

Now I don't know the content of your `./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh` file, but if it's well written, then it should return an exit code indicating whether it runs successfully or not (e.g.: using `exit 0` for successful run, `exit 1` for failed run, `exit 2` for other kind of error)

After that, we can see the exit code of last command by `echo $?`

So, you might want to rewrite your code to:

```
String command="./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh > /dev/null 2>&1 ; \n echo $?";
```

Explanation:

- execute a command in file called `./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh` (from its extension, I assume it's a shell script)
- `> /dev/null` = then redirect its `STDOUT` to `/dev/null` (a.k.a.: discard the output)
- `2>&1` = then redirect its `STDERR` to wherever `STDOUT` goes (as stated above, its gone to /dev/null or discarded)
- `;` = after finish executing this command, execute next command
- `\n echo $?` = then echo (print in STDOUT) the exit code of last command

Note that after this change, you won't have the PID of the process but instead have the exit code instead. And this change also make your java program to wait the bash script to finish instead.

So if your bash script runs for 5 minute, and you start executing your java program in 08:00:00,

- previously, your java program should finish in about 08:00:01 (very fast since it doesn't wait for bash script to finish)
- after the change, your java program will finish in about 08:05:01 (since it waited for the bash script to finish before exiting)

### Edit:

OP said that

> The business requirements are to launch a script in a remote machine in background, so I can't wait for the complete execution of the script. My personal solution is to get the PID at SSH launch time and then make another inquiry to the remote system

You can always save the exit code to a file, then read that file later, example:

In `./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh`, instead of writing `exit 0` or `exit 1`, you can write

```
echo 0 >> ./export/home/therock/test/result.txt
exit 0
```

later when you want to check the result, you just need to read last line of `./export/home/therock/test/result.txt` (e.g.: `tail -n1 ./export/home/therock/test/result.txt`)

### Edit 2:

OP said that he/she needs to know if the process is already finished or not.

Easy approach to this is to simply create a lock file (or a reverse lock file)

In beginning of `./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh`, add:

```
rm -f ./export/home/therock/test/result.txt
```

And then, instead of writing `exit 0` or `exit 1`, you can write

```
echo 0 > ./export/home/therock/test/result.txt
exit 0
```

So you know that the bash script is still running if file `./export/home/therock/test/result.txt` does not exist. And if the file exist, it means the bash script is finished and you can read its content to see its result.

Other approach (more recommended) is to write a lock file that gets created when bash script process started, and gets deleted when its exited. This way it also ensure that your bash script is only executed once at a time.

Comment: You can always save the exit code to a file, then read that file later

Comment: Thank you Kristian, you have explained very well!!!
The business requirements are to launch a script in background on remote machines. Those scripts could take some seconds/hours, we don't know. So I can't stay in waiting for the complete executions. My personal solution is to get the PID at SSH launch time and then make another inquiry to the remote system: 

ps -p [PID] -o etime   => in order to get the elapsed execution time
So if I will get ELAPSED time... I know it's still in running otherwise the script is just finished but I can't garantee if the script was run or not.

Comment: @Alex73 you can use lock file to track if a process is still running or not

Comment: Hi Kristian, we can't manage the script on third parties server. We have only to launch the Script via SSH. I can't ask them to add lines to the script. The script must run and we have to garantee the execution. My idea is to check if the script is present and it is executable. Than I launch the SCRIPT optaining a PID and then ask to the remote system if the PID exists and still in running. If it is already in running this means ... is executed. If it is finished the pid doesn't exist anymore but I can assume it was run. How can I do this? The inquiry if PID is still in running?

Comment: ```I can't ask them to add lines to the script``` >> if you can launch the script via ssh then you can also add lines to the script, e.g.: ```ssh user@host -t 'echo A_LINE_TO_BE_ADDED_TO_SCRIPT >> ./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh'```

Comment: then you can also see if the content of the script by ```ssh user@host -t 'cat ./export/home/therock/test/hello.bsh'```